# i want to pass my span class value into controller in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to pass my span class value into controller in spring mvc. This is my code:

```
  $("#SscpreviewDiv").click(function(){
                       $("#myModal").modal('show');

                      var firstname=$("#firstname").val();
                      var middlename=$("#middlename").val();
                      var lastname=$("#lastname").val();

                     var datetimepicker=$("#datetimepicker").val();
                      //var datetimepicker=$('#datetimepicker :selected').attr("value");
                     var gender=$("#gender").val();
                      var contact=$("#contact").val();
                      var city=$("#city").val();
                      var pincode=$("#pincode").val();
                      var 
         phisically_challenged=$("#physically_challenged").val();
                      var category=$("#category").val();
                      var ssc_marks=$("#ssc_mark").val();

          $(".firstname").text(firstname);
                      $(".middlename").text(middlename);
                      $(".lastname").text(lastname);

                     $(".datetimepicker").text(datetimepicker);
                     $(".gender").text(gender);
                      $(".contact").text(contact);
                       $(".city").text(city);
                      $(".pincode").text(pincode);


<form:form action="saveSscDetailsonPreview" 
    modelAttribute="sscAdmissionProcessBean"  method="Post">       
    <div class="divborder "  style="padding-left: 15px;" >
    <div class="detailsBorder"  align="center">
       <strong><i><span class="fullname"></span></i></strong></h3>
       <div class="col-10 varela ">
            <table  class="table-hover table table-striped table-bordered" >
                <thead style="color: black" id="examtable" >
                <tr><th width="50%;">Firstname</th><td> <span  class="firstname" id="firstname" ></span></td></tr>
                         <tr><th width="50%;">Middlename</th><td> <span class="middlename"></span></td></tr>
                         <tr><th width="50%;">Lastname</th><td> <span class="lastname"></span></td></tr> 
                         <tr><th>date Of Birth</th><td> <span class="datetimepicker"></span></td></tr>   
                         <tr><th>Contact</th><td><span class="contact"></span></td></tr>
                         <tr><th>Gender</th><td><span class="gender"></span></td></tr>
                         <tr><th>Category</th><td><span class="category"></span></td></tr>
                         <tr><th>City</th><td><span class="city"></span></td></tr>
                         <tr><th>SSC Marks</th><td><span class="ssc_mark"></span></td></tr>
                         <tr><th>Passing Year</th><td><span class="monthyear"></span></td></tr>
                         <tr><th>Course</th><td><span class="ssc_select_course"></span></td></tr>
                         <tr><th>Stream</th><td><span class="ssc_select_stream"></span></td></tr>
                         <tr><th>Physically Challenge</th><td><span class="phisically_challenged"></span></td></tr>
                         <tr><th>Mode</th><td><span class="select_mode"></span></td></tr>
                         <tr><th>ApplyDate</th><td><span 
   class="sscApplyDate"></span></td></tr> 
                </thead>
            </table>``
            </div>
      </div>
 <button id="savePreviewDetails">Print Your Form</button>  
      </div>
    </form:form>

 im setting text field value into span class using ajax and display model 
 class but i after display im trying to save span class  to controller value getting null plz tell me what happen?
```

im setting text field value into span class using ajax and display model 
     class but i after display im trying to save span class  to controller value getting null plz tell me what h im setting text field value into span class using ajax and display model 
     class but i after display im trying to save span class  to controller value getting null plz tell me what h im setting text field value into span class using ajax and display model 
     class but i after display im trying to save span class  to controller value getting null plz tell me what h im setting text field value into span class using ajax and display model 
     class but i after display im trying to save span class  to controller value getting null plz tell me what h im setting text field value into span class using ajax and display model 
     class but i after display im trying to save span class  to controller value getting null plz tell me what h im setting text field value into span class using ajax and display model 
     class but i after display im trying to save span class  to controller value getting null plz tell me what h

Answer (score 2):

`<span>` is not `input` OR `Select`. You should use  `input` OR `Select` to send value to Controller.

Try to add extra `hidden` field and set to it with value.

e.g.

```
<strong><i><span class="fullname">
    <input type="hidden" name="fullname" id="id-fullname">
    //OR
    <form:hidden path="fullname">
</span></i></strong>
```

And in jQuery

```
$('id-fullname').val(fullname);
```